# Document Clustering and Visualization

Tags: python, doc2vec

I would like to test if a set of documents have some special similarity, looking on a graph built with each one's vector representation, showed together with a text dataset of other documents. I guess that they will be together in a visualization.

The solution is to use doc2vec to calculate the vector for each document and plot it? Can it be done in a unsupervised way? Which python library should I use to get those beautiful 2D and 3D representations of Word2vec?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you're asking but if you want a way to check if vector are of the same type you could use K-Means.
K-Means make a number K of cluster out of a list of vector, so if you choose a good K (not too low so it will search for something but not too high so it will not be too discriminant) it could work.

K-Means grossly work that way:

```
init_center(K) # randomly set K vector that will be the center of your cluster

while not converge(): # This one is tricky as you can find a lot of way to check for the convergence, the easiest is to check if your center has moved since the last itteration

    associate_vector() # Here you associate all the vectors to the closest center

    re_calculate_center() # And now you put the center at the... well center of their point, you can do that just by doing the mean of all the vector of the cluster.
```

This gif is probably clearer than me:
[image: Gif K-mean]

And this article (where this gif is from) is really clearer than me, even if he talk for java here: 
https://picoledelimao.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/multithreaded-k-means-in-java/